# Problems with addFrameScript on an instance

Tags: actionscript, label, frame

I'm trying to add a frame script via:

```
private function addFrameScript(mc:MovieClip, label:String, func:Function, arg:*):void {
    var labels:Array = mc.currentLabels;
    var i:int = labels.length;

    while (--i > -1) {
        if (FrameLabel(labels[i]).name == label) {
            mc.addFrameScript(FrameLabel(labels[i]).frame-1, func(arg));
            return;
        }
    }



    trace("WARNING: The label '" + label + "' does not exist in the MovieClip '" + mc.name + "'");
}

private function dispatchFrameEvent(labelName:String):void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event(labelName, true));
}

addFrameScript(instanceName, "end", dispatchFrameEvent, "end");
```

But it doesn't seem to be adding and I can't figure out why. Normally I add Frame scripts to the main timeline, but not to an instance on the timeline (as in the example above).

Clearly there's something I'm missing...is there a way to trace out my frame script to see if it's even being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that addFrameScript functions being added take no arguments. so whatever func you are passing in must must return a function with no arguments

so your dispatchFrameEvent should look like this

```
private function dispatchFrameEvent(labelName:String):Function {
   return function func():void{
     dispatchEvent(new Event(labelName, true));
   }
}
```